# Use query result to load nodes for jsTree on user request

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, jstree

I've been reasearching a lot but I couldn't find the right answer.

I want to know how to generate a jsTree on demand and the nodes have to be loaded from the data contained in a database.
The data will be returned by a function.

My purpose is when the user clicks on a node the script generate only the sons of that node based on the database query.

To do that I tried many scripts that I found here and the most similar with what I want to do is that one:

$("#tree-cat1").jstree({

```
"plugins": ["themes", "json_data", "ui"],
"themes": {"theme": "classic","dots": true,"icons": true},
"json_data": {
      //root elements
    "data": [{"data":'A node',"state":'closed',"attr":{"id":'A'}}], 
    "ajax": {
        "type": 'POST',
        "data": {"action": 'getChildren'},
        "url": function (node) { 
            var nodeId = node.attr('id'); //id="A"

            return 'yuorPathTo/GetChildrenScript/' + nodeId;
        },
        "success": function (new_data) {
            //where new_data = node children 
            //e.g.: [{'data':'A1 node','attr':{'id':'A1'}}, {'data':'A2 node','attr':{'id':'A2'}}]
            return new_data;
        }
    }
}
```

});

It was written originally from Irishka.

The problem is I couldn't make it work. The main issue is to know what  data is being returned when you make the call "return yuorPathTo/GetChildrenScript/" and if someone can give an example of that data.

Any help will be appreciate.

Answer (score 0):

It requires an JSON-format Data. For example:

`[{"attr":{"id":"1","rel":"folder"},"data":"FolderName1","state":""},{"attr":{"id":"2","rel":"folder"},"data":"FolderName2","state":""}]`

Comment: The point is I'm trying to add some data to the return statement to test if the code works because later on I will add a function to return more data. So what I did is:

return "[{'data':'A node','state':'closed','attr':{'id':'A'}}]";

But when I put the data it does not work then the question would be what should I put there to make the code work.

Comment: working script: 
$(.tree).jstree({
  "plugins" : [ "json_data", "ui", "crrm", "dnd" ],
  "json_data" : {
    "ajax" : {
      "url" : "ajax.php",
      "data" : function (n) {
        return {
          "id" : n.attr ? n.attr("id") : 0
        };
      }
    }
  }
})

Comment: I'm trying your script but there are some things that I don't get:
$(.tree).jstree({

Comment: I'm trying your script but there are some things that I don't get:
** $(.tree).jstree({ ** I had to change ** .tree ** by ** #tree ** because otherwise the script does not run, I don't know what is doing that. Then the line ** "url" : "ajax.php" ** I guess that is my file from where i will take the data i need right? Otherwise i don't know what is the purpose of that. What is doing that function? **"data" : function (n) { return { "id" : n.attr ? n.attr("id") : 0 };} ** I mean because I'm a newbie with this i don't understand exactly what is doing. Thanks a million.

Comment: So.. "ajax.php" is your 'yuorPathTo/GetChildrenScript/'. But in your code example it is "'yuorPathTo/GetChildrenScript/' + nodeId" and if nodeId='A' result will be: 'yuorPathTo/GetChildrenScript/A'. I think it should be 'yuorPathTo/GetChildrenScript.php' without nodeId. Go next. "data" : function (n) { return { "id" : n.attr ? n.attr("id") : 0 };} - returns nodeId. In your case it will be "A1". if yet there is no nodes it returns 0. You can replace 0 by your base parent node id.

Answer (score 0):

Well i'll try to write code that you need..

In html we have empty div#tree-cat1

`<div id="tree-cat1"></div>`

In JS:

```
$("#tree-cat1").jstree({
    "plugins": ["themes", "json_data", "ui"],
    "themes": {"theme": "classic","dots": true,"icons": true},
    "json_data": {
        "ajax": {
            "type": 'POST',
            "url": 'yuorPathTo/GetChildrenScript.php',
            "data": function (n) {
                return {
                    // This is variables that send in POST to PHP script
                    "action": 'getChildren',
                    "id" : n.attr ? n.attr("id") : "A1" // A1 is most parent node. You can change it by your parent id. This string mean: if node has id - we get it's childs, but if node has not id (there is no nodes) - we get first parent node
                }

            }
        }
    }
}
```

The PHP script in "yuorPathTo/GetChildrenScript.php" for example might look like this:

```
$result = array(); // Array for json
$id=$_GET['id']*1;
// This query selects children of this parent and for each child selects count of its own children
$query = "SELECT id, name, rel, cnt FROM
   (
      SELECT id, name, rel FROM yourTabe WHERE parent_id = '$id'
   ) v_1, (
      SELECT parent_id, COUNT(*) as cnt FROM yourTable GROUP BY parent_id
   ) v_2
   WHERE v_1.id = v_2.parent_id
";
$res = $dbh->query($query);
while ($row = $res->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $helper = array(); // Array for each Node's Data
    $helper['attr']['id'] = 'A'.$row['id'];
    $helper['attr']['rel'] = $row['rel'];
    $helper['data']  = $row['name'];
    $helper['state'] = $row['cnt'] > 0 ? 'closed' : ''; // if state='closed' this node can be opened
    $rezult[] = $helper;
}
echo json_encode($rezult);
```

Comment: Hi man, let's say that I want to load the same two nodes again a again endlessly. Instead of 'yuorPathTo/GetChildrenScript.php' can I use 'flatData.xml' ? Because I have the two nodes written in the xml file and I want to load them again and again but I tried changing that line and it didn't work.

Comment: You can load xml-data in PHP-script (http://ru2.php.net/xml) and then return it in json-format to JS

Comment: Well, the thing is the file that I'm modifying is in jsp so I don't think I can use php or php script, I could write a java function that returns a JSON Object but I don't know if its possible.

Comment: http://www.json.org/java/ and example: `JSONObject myObj = new JSONObject();
myObj.put("key1", "val1");
myObj.put("key2", "val2");
myObj.put("key3", "val3");
JSONArray myArr = new JSONArray();
myArr.put("a");
myArr.put("b");
myArr.put("c");
myObj.put("key4",myArr);
System.out.println(myObj.toString());` Result will be: `{"key4":["a","b","c"],"key3":"val3","key2":"val2","key1":"val1"}`

Comment: Also you can ask a question about Java and Json on stackoverflow

Comment: Sorry, I know that the object exists but I wanted to say that once I requested the info from the server and I convert it into a JSON Object, how can i give that JSON object that contains the info I want to represent to the jsTree: 
Example: could be possible to do that?
"url": 'new JSONObject()'

Comment: Would you like to run `"url": 'new JSONObject()'` in JS? JS don't knows about JSONObject()

Comment: Okey now i realised why. I'm starting from scrath from the sample code but is not working. I left another question here: asking similar thing.